# Stop child from triggering parent event in hammer.js

Tags: javascript, dom-events, hammer.js

When binding an hammer event to a element, the event is also triggered by it's child element. Using `stopPropagation` to keep the event from bubbling up doesn't seem to work.

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var hammertime = new Hammer(document.getElementById('parent'));

hammertime.on('tap', function(e) {
    e.srcEvent.stopPropagation();
    alert('Clicked on ' + e.target.id);
});
```

See JSFiddle for example: http://jsfiddle.net/qqvyqzgh/3/

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @Guglie's answer,
For a more general case, add a class to all elements in children you want to disable the hammer event:

```
<div>
  Drag me
  <input class='disableHammer' type="range" placeholder="Don't drag me"></input>
</div>
```

and;

```
hammertime.on('pan', function(e) {
  if(e.target.classList.contains("disableHammer")) alert('Stop dragging him.');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the target of the event is the parent element.

```js
var element = document.getElementById('parent');
var hammertime = new Hammer(element);

hammertime.on('tap', function (e) {
    if(e.target === element) {
        alert('Clicked on ' + e.target.id);
    }
});
```

Here's [your updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qqvyqzgh/4/).

Comment: Hi @guglie your answers helped me to get in the right direction. However I have a parent container with lots of child elements. And one of the child element has different event. How would you manage if you have different target value? Thanks

Comment: Hi @Mesmerize86, if the child which needs to react to tap is only one probably you can just put simply another clause `} else if (e.target === child_element) { /*do stuff for child*/ }`